# How to render an array of strings using map in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, jsx

I basically want to put each string in the array in a separated div, I'm trying to do this but is not rendering anything

```
export default class Loja extends Component {
      state = {
        loja: {},
        lojaInfo: {},
        category: []
      }

      async componentDidMount() {
        const { id } = this.props.match.params;

        const response = await api.get(`/stores/${id}`);

        const { category, ...lojaInfo } = response.data

        this.setState({ loja: category, lojaInfo });

        console.log(category)

      }

      render() {
        const { category } = this.state;


        return (

            <p>{category.map(cat => <div>{cat}</div>)}</p>

        );
      }
    }
```

The console.log(category) shows this:

[image]

Comment: You're not updating the category part of the state in this line `this.setState({ loja: category, lojaInfo });`

Comment: Sorry im kinda new on react can you show in code?

Comment: The field category in state is always an empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that you're updating 2 properties inside the `componentDidMount`, one is `loja: category` and the second property is `lojaInfo`, but in the `render()` method you're accessing `this.state.category` which still is an empty string.

What you want to do instead is, inside of your `componentDidMount` update your state like this:

```
this.setState({
  category,
  lojaInfo,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you've added your `category` into the `loja` object in the state.

something like this should work:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    const { id } = this.props.match.params;
    const response = await api.get(`/stores/${id}`);
    const { category, ...lojaInfo } = response.data
    this.setState({ category, lojaInfo });
}
```